# Remove URL user credentials before pass to Reverse Proxy - Apache

Tags: apache

i am trying to configure apache as a reverse proxy with basic auth. The problem is that URL credentials should not be proxied to the service (`http://localhost:8000`).

For example: if the user access `http://user:password@my-host.com` , the URL credentials should not be passed like `http://user:password@localhost:8000`, it should be just `http://localhost:8000`

The conf file:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ProxyRequests off
 

        <Location />
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "namex"
          AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
          Require valid-use
          ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic base64userpass"
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

How should i do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Are they being passed along?  You clearly did not write it as such in your `ProxyPass` directive.  If it is being passed in an authentication header, you can disable that (search for that, responses abound).  Worst case, you can use tcpdump to see what is being send exactly (auth header or user:password:).  FYI look at adding a `ProxyPassReverse`.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Nic3500! The URL credentials are being fowarded to the service and i'm getting an error because of it. `Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials`. I'll take a look at `ProxyPassReverse` and try it!

Comment: I did not expect that the credentials were being sent.  Ok so you need to do a proxy configuration, and manipulate the request.  You can use `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag to do that.